# Strange results in AutoSuggestBox in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to use the standard `AutoSuggestBox` in a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app, but it behaves really strangely.

In a simple demo, I have collection

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d"
        };
```

and he AutoSuggestBox in XAML:

```
<AutoSuggestBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

The problem is that no matter what I write to the `AutoSuggestBox`, I always get all the items:

[image]

The documentation says next to nothing and I have not found any samples using this control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this blog post](http://prabathsl.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/autosuggestbox-in-winows-phone-81.html), it looks like what you're expecting (automatic filtering) isn't the case - instead, you need to hook into the `TextChanged` event and populate the `Suggestions` collection yourself.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx):

> The app is notified when text has been changed by the user and is responsible for providing relevant suggestions for this control to display.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code:

```
    private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender,
        AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string myString in PreviouslyDefinedStringArray)
            {
                if (myString.Contains(sender.Text) == true)
                {
                    myList.Add(myString);
                }
            }
            sender.ItemsSource = myList;
    }
```

This should work on WP 8.1

Comment: a bit redundant, when I already accepted an answer telling me the same

Comment: it is absolutely ok to post code; the blog post mentioned in the accepted answer might become unavailable or relocate in the future. The event handler code should be wrapped in `if(args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput) { ... }` to avoid redundancy when a suggestion is chosen, or the text is changed programmatically.