# Autocomplete textbox in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want in my windows phone 8.1 app some feature,that my user input some character and I suggest him some word.

```
public IEnumerable AutoCompletions = new List<string>()
{
 "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "Nullam", "felis", "dui", "gravida", "at"};
```

for example user input "a" and i suggest "amet","at" and "adipiscing", further user input "am" and i suggest "amet".
Help me please

Comment: As far as i know, it's still unavailable for `WP8.1`!

Comment: really?
In market i many app viewed with this feature

Comment: maybe you are don't understand
example
https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC737492.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is display only the suggestions that apply for the given input. Not all possible strings.

Lets assume you have the following AutoSuggestBox:

```
<AutoSuggestBox 
   TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
   SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen">
    <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

These are the event handlers:

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            // You can set a threshold when to start looking for suggestions
            if (sender.Text.Length > 3)
            {
                sender.ItemsSource = getSuggestions(sender.Text); 
            }
            else {
                sender.ItemsSource = new List<String> { };
            }
        }
    }
```

All you have to do is to write a `getSuggestions(String text)` method that returns plausible suggestions for a given input.

Comment: maybe help other users
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637192/strange-results-in-autosuggestbox-in-windows-phone-8-1