# AutoSuggestBox is not working properly in windows phone 8.1 runtime app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have used AutoCompleteBox in windows phone 8(Silverlight app) which is working perfectly but here in autosuggestbox i cannot find the ItemFilter property, even though if i use TextChanged event it is not giving the relavant suggestion. My code is below.

Xaml Code:

```
    <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="suggestions" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,62,0,0" 
ItemsSource="{Binding }" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="296" TextChanged="suggestions_TextChanged" 
SuggestionChosen="suggestions_SuggestionChosen"/>
```

C# Code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            suggestions.ItemsSource = Suggestions;
        }


        private void suggestions_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
            {
                Suggestions.Clear();

                Suggestions.Add("Nambukarthy Raveendran");
                Suggestions.Add("Jeyanthan Periyasami");
                Suggestions.Add("Vijay Selvamm");
                Suggestions.Add("Ashraf Ali");

                List<string> myList = new List<string>();
                foreach (string myString in Suggestions)
                {
                    if (myString.Contains(sender.Text) == true)
                    {
                        myList.Add(myString);
                    }
                }
                sender.ItemsSource = myList;

            }
        }

        private void suggestions_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
        {
            suggestions.Text = "Choosen";
        }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the suggestions you wanted to, within the `TextChanged` event:

[Strange results in AutoSuggestBox in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637192/), could help you.

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/08/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-what-controls-are-new.aspx)